# jQuery(Ajax) problem in Internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax

The Code-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "edit.php",
    success: function(html)
    {
     $("#last").html(html).hide().slideDown('slow');
         alert("hello");
    }
});
```

Mozilla shows it all fine. Where as IE (being the normal PMS *****) doesn't load anything into #last but does show the alert, what could be the problem?

I thought javascript was browser independent?

Comment: Is there only one element with the ID `#last` on the page?

Comment: `#load` or `#last`? Try `alert($('[id=load]').length);` to see if there are any duplicate ID's on the page (or substitute `load` for `last`, depending on which ID you're actually using.)

Comment: darlin's answer below worked. But i can't get the animation to work, even on Mozilla it doesn't work without hide() first. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the url:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'edit.php',
    success: function(html) {
        $('#last').html(html).hide().slideDown('slow');
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: The quotes are there, sorry typo.

Comment: If you remove the `.hide().slideDown('slow')` part, is it working properly? Also why are you calling the `.hide()` method? Also shouldn't you inverse the order of `.hide` and `.slideDown` calls: `$('#last').html(html).slideDown('slow').hide();`

Comment: Yes, that works :]. But i'm not able to get the animation now :[